# CI Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script

Tags: codeigniter, classloader

I get an error when I load the signing script. The error is as follows:

> Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script
>   libraries/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php on line 20

I think it's a hack problem because when I see my file ClassLoader.php

[image: image here]

All my project files have the same lines on first statement!

How to protect my code in order to avoid the error next time?

Comment: By "hack problem" do you mean you think your server and therefore code has been hacked?  The error is very clear in what it is saying.  You've got a line of code which is `namespace something;`, but it's not the first item of code being read

Comment: yes, the error is clear but i want to know how to protect my code in order to ovoide the error next time !

Comment: You should probably burn that file with fire - like NOW. And then read http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/ several times. But I'm pretty sure that you're problem isn't insecure PHP code - you would have done something really aweful, because CI usually helps a lot - so maybe also burn your server. Or ask your sysadmin what the hell is going on.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! i will contact my sysadmin server !